# Moving Docker Images from Nexus Repository to Azure Container Registry

Tags: docker, image, migration, nexus, acr

I have almost 500 GB of Docker Images in a Private Nexus Repository. I want to migrate it to Azure Container Registry. I have tried running "az acr import" utility using AzureCloud CLI. The connection to the private Nexus Registry seems getting initiated (As I could see an output like \Running......) but then nothing happens and nothing is imported from the Nexus. I am using admin credentials.

Could anyone help me with a way to swiftly move these images across the registries?

### Command i ran -

az acr import
–name myregistry
–source nexusrepo_dns_name/sourcerepo/sourceimage:tag
–image sourceimage:tag
–username
–password